# getting a scroll bar on right and bottom of modal bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am getting a scrollbar on right and bottom of the modal. I had removed the footer section . Still its showing the space and I am getting scrolls on both right and left side. I am displaying an image in my modal. how to remove this scrolls and fix the issue?

**Here's mt HTML**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">modal title</h4>
      </div>
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
       <img src="img/model/logo.jpeg" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**And CSS-**

```
#myModal {
  top:10%;
    width:445px;
    left: 35%;
outline: none;
}

.modal-body {
    position:relative;
      width: auto;
    height:auto;/* This avoids image to go off the container */
}

.modal-dialog{
    width: 440px;
}
```

Comment: add `overflow:hidden` to the container

Comment: Thanks man! a silly one! :)